# Horizontal Split Value bar - Android

Tags: android

[image: Please find the attached image for your reference, the same horizontal progress bar i need by which i can show the remaining or completed data.]

I need to develop the horizontal split value bar to show the remaining or completed data. There would be 2 horizontal bar - 1 which will have grayed out color and one which will have a filled color by which i need to show some amount of data which user has already used. Please give your input if some of you already have done this.

thanks in advance

Comment: Please find the image for your reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void showBillCycleProgress(int billCycleProgressBarId, int total, int progress, int fillProgressDrawable, int blankProgressDrawable, View view2) {
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view2.findViewById(billCycleProgressBarId);
    layout.removeAllViews();
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        View view = new View(getActivity());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(35, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 3, 0);
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        view.setBackgroundResource(fillProgressDrawable);
        if (i >= progress) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(new AnonymousClass(this, view, blankProgressDrawable), (long) (((total - i) * 50) + 200));
        }
        layout.addView(view);
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally got the way to do the above design progress volumn bar.